# Where to find Hg/Git technical support?

Tags: git, mercurial, commercial, technical-support

I would like to out who provides technical support (commercial) for two major DVCS's of today: Git and Mercurial.

This is for a place where they've been using Subversion for some time and now they're renewing their software licences. Although they will be keeping Subversion as well, they would like to justify beginning of DVCS as an alternative system. Most people root for Mercurial since it seems simpler; mostly engineers and physicians there who are not that interested in checking Git repos for corruption and the finer workings of Git, but I believe any one of the two could "pass".

The system has to have a price (can be zero; no problem there) and some sort of official technical support. It is a *pro forma* matter, but it has to be specified.

***So, I'm asking you: do you know where could one go for commercial Git or Mercurial technical support?***

Technical forums and the like are out of the question. It has to work on the principle:

- *I have a problem.*
- *I post a question with the details.*
- *I get an answer in specified time. It can be "we cannot do that." but it has to be an official answer and given in agreed time.*

I'm sure by now most of you understand what I'm asking, but if not — post a comment or similar.

Also, if you think of any reasons which could decide justification of introducing Git/Hg from an technical and administrative viewpoint, feel free to write them down also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of the following companies that offer support for Mercurial:

- [aragost Trifork](http://www.aragost.com/en/services/mercurial/)
- [Selenic consulting](http://www.selenic.com/)

Don't know of a company that offers support for Git though.

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks for answering. You haven't had any experience with any of them by any chance?

Comment: No, not personally I haven't.

Comment: What about Fog Creek? If you have trouble with Kiln they'll help.

Answer (score 2):

I know of a freebook that might be useful and other links:

- [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialBook)
- [Mercurial Home Page](http://hg-scm.org/)
- [Mercurial Support](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Support) - this might be of most use (it is commericial support, but a link to free support too)

Hope this helps, if not then I apologise.

**EDIT: removed GitHub link (http://support.github.com/) (see comments)**

Comment: Just might, a bit - I'll forward him the list of companies from that last link (from what I gather Selenic offers commercial support for Mercurial? You haven't had any experience with them in that matter by any chance?).

Comment: @Rook, no I have no experience with them.

Comment: I saw the GitHub's page but from what I could gather they only offer support for projects related to them (i.e. hosted on GitHub...), not Git in general.

Comment: @Rook - ok, I will remove that link. A colleague of mine has used them before, thats why I listed them. I have no experience with then either.

Comment: No, you don't have to. Not because of me. Besides, maybe I'm wrong and someone will know more.

Comment: Selenic is the Matt Mackall's company. He's the Mercurial project leader. I'm another core Mercurial developer, and I work for aragost Trifork. We've done several migrations to Mercurial, including training and customization. You're of course welcome to get in touch if you want to hear more.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said forums are out of the question so this is for others who would consider forums: have a look at http://kiln.stackexchange.com/. A lot of Hg questions have been answered there.

Comment: Thank you. I know of kiln and its board. But as I mentioned, it is not an acceptable solution in some environments.